# Esoteric quote that inspired Nolan's 'Inception'

Tags: dialogue, inception, christopher-nolan

I remember once reading a very esoteric, borderline nonsensical quote somewhere on the old IMDb boards which was apparently one of Nolan's inspirations for the film **Inception**. It had very few conjunctive words, and possibly included the words 'inside' and 'behind'.

Maybe something like **'Inside Behind, Open. Above Depth, Removed.'**

Or something!

Can anyone help?

Comment: This sounds like one of the 64 hexagram titles found in the *I Ching*. However, there are several translations, and this is probably from one particular translation that is likely still under copyright, so simple Internet searches might never yield a hit. Maybe start by getting ahold of the most popular translation and reading all the titles?

Comment: Christopher Nolan directed 'Memento' based upon his brothers short-story. C. Nolan also talked about that story and film as an influence to 'Inception' (along with 'The Matrix', 'Dark City', 'The Thirteenth Floor'--L.A. Times 04 April, 2010). Is it possibly one of the tattoos/clues from 'Memento'? E.g. 'She is Gone. Time still passes'. Or, perhaps, a quote from Jonathan Nolan's short-story 'Memento Mori'..? E. g. "Time is three things for most people, but for you, for us, just one. A singularity. One moment."

Comment: Thanks but no - it was barely a sentence. It was very mystical and took some figuring out, grammatically.